# Error: template std.array.Appender!(string).Appender.put does not match any function

Tags: d

I get an error

```
Error: template std.array.Appender!(string).Appender.put does not match any 
function template declaration
```

I am trying to use the `Appender`. Can you tell me how to make it work?

```
import std.array;
import std.stdio;

    void app(inout Appender!(string) as)
    {
       char ch = 'o';
       as.put(ch);
    }

    void main()
    {
       auto app2 = appender!string();
       //writeln(typeid(app));
       app2.put('g');
       app(app2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `inout` to `ref`.

`inout` is used to transfer `cont`/`immutable`/*`none`* attribute from function arguments to its parameters. `ref` is for transferring function arguments by references.